# Populate Array with Objects (dateTime)

Tags: c#

My error is in my for statement and the syntax error is saying that my constructor does not take three arguements.

```
        string[] first = new string[20] { "Scott", "Ramona", "Todd", "Melissa", "Naomi", "Leland", "Conor", "Julie", "Armondo", "Leah",
                                          "Frank", "Peter", "Ila", "Mandy", "Sammy", "Gareth", "Garth", "Wayne", "Freddy", "Mark" };

        string[] last = new string[20] { "Kennedy", "Kennedy", "Kennedy", "Kennedy", "Kennedy", "Kennedy", "Carrel", "MaloyTheBeautiful", "Johnson", "Smith", 
                                         "Sinatra", "Clemens", "Eels", "Johnson", "Eels", "Thompson", "Brooks", "World", "Crugar", "Thomas" };
        DateTime[] birth = new DateTime[20];
        birth[0] = new DateTime(1987, 22, 7);
        birth[1] = new DateTime(1962, 15, 9);
        birth[2] = new DateTime(1984, 21, 4);
        birth[3] = new DateTime(1977, 24, 1);
        birth[4] = new DateTime(1983, 12, 8);
        birth[5] = new DateTime(1979, 14, 1);
        birth[6] = new DateTime(1965, 19, 9);
        birth[7] = new DateTime(1968, 21, 2);
        birth[8] = new DateTime(1980, 22, 7);
        birth[9] = new DateTime(1982, 20, 7);
        birth[10] = new DateTime(1984, 19, 4);
        birth[11] = new DateTime(1968, 11, 9);
        birth[12] = new DateTime(1968, 21, 8);
        birth[13] = new DateTime(1975, 5, 2);
        birth[14] = new DateTime(1945, 15, 3);
        birth[15] = new DateTime(1969, 14, 6);
        birth[16] = new DateTime(1987, 141, 4);
        birth[17] = new DateTime(1976, 23, 5);
        birth[18] = new DateTime(1989, 28, 6);
        birth[19] = new DateTime(1988, 23, 9);

        // Populate Array Person[] People = new Person[20];     


        for (int i = 0; i < People.Length; i++)
        {
            People[i]= new Person(first[i], last[i], birth[i]);
        }
```

My Class Looks like this

```
public class Person
{
    private string _firstname;
    private string _lastname;
    private DateTime _birthDate;

    public void Personn(string firstname, string lastname, DateTime birthDate)
    {
        _firstname = firstname;
        _lastname = lastname;
        _birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public string Firstname
    { get { return _firstname; } }

    public string Lastname
    { get { return _lastname; } }

    public DateTime Birthdate
    { get { return _birthDate; } }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
 public void Personn(string firstname, string lastname, DateTime birthDate)
```

use

```
 public Person(string firstname, string lastname, DateTime birthDate)
```

Comment: WOW lol thx so much. im making too many dumb mistakes. I appreciate this and im new as a user so how do i give you a good answer for koodo's

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < People.Length; i++)
            {
                richTxtDisplay.AppendText(People[i].Firstname + People[i].Lastname + People[i].Birthdate + "\n"); //Is this how i display
            }

Comment: @thanatus As others have said, the difference between a method and a constructor is: (1) The name of a constructor must be the same as the name of the class, and the name of a method must be distinct from the name of the class. (2) A constructor cannot specify a return type (like `void` or `int` or `Person`), but a method must specify one. // If you don't write any constructors, the compilers will make a `public` constructor for you that takes 0 arguments. Then you can say `new Person()`, but not `new Person(f, l, b)`. If you do write constructor(s), the compiler won't create additional ones.

Answer (score 2):

What you think is a constructor is just a method. You have misspelled the class name.

Change this:

```
    public void Personn(string firstname, string lastname, DateTime birthDate)
```

to:

```
    public Person(string firstname, string lastname, DateTime birthDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your constructor, it shouldn't have a return type an should be the same name as the class.

Comment: @PoweRoy: It **has** a return type: void. So it's not a valid constructor, but a normal method. It's also named wrong (`Personn` instead of `Person`).

Comment: Oh yes, I totally missed that

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use instead of this line:

```
 public void Personn(string firstname, string lastname, DateTime birthDate)
```

this one:

```
 public Person(string firstname, string lastname, DateTime birthDate)
```

Because currently it is a void method instead of a constructor, however you have a default constructor which has no parameter in this case. That could be a reson for your problem!

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Constructor does not have any return type. Remove `void` from your constructor.

Comment: how do i display it now im getting another problem